# Python: Identify column that has greatest value

Tags: python, csv

Say I have five columns of data in n rows:

```
0.0374 0.1311 0.1502 0.5761 0.1052
0.0117 0.0301 0.1748 0.5980 0.1854
0.1261 0.7332 0.1182 0.0156 0.0069
```

For each row, I would like to be able to identify the column number that contains the maximum value. In the first row of my sample data, for example, column 3 (zero-based indexing) has the max() value; for the second row, column 3 again has the max value; for the third row, column 1 has the max value. I can write an inefficient method that identifies the column with the largest value, but is there an elegant solution to this problem? I welcome any and all advice others can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

**`mytsv.tsv`:**

```
0.0374 0.1311 0.1502 0.5761 0.1052
0.0117 0.0301 0.1748 0.5980 0.1854
0.1261 0.7332 0.1182 0.0156 0.0069
```

Code:

```
>>> contents = open('mytsv.tsv')
>>> linenum = 0
>>> for line in contents:
...     linenum+=1
...     print 'The maximum in line %d is in column %d' %(linenum, line.index(max(line.split())))
... 
The maximum in line 1 is in column 3
The maximum in line 2 is in column 3
The maximum in line 3 is in column 1
>>>
```

It isn't exactly *elegant*, but it is relatively pythonic. If you want me to try to shrink it down even further, I can.

Here is the one-liner:

```
['The maximum in line %d is in column %d' %(linenum, line.split().index(max(line.split()))) for linenum, line in enumerate(open('mytsv.tsv'))]
```

Which can be used as such:

```
>>> for k in ['The maximum in line %d is in column %d' %(linenum, line.split().index(max(line.split()))) for linenum, line in enumerate(open('mytsv.tsv'))]:
...     print k
... 
The maximum in line 0 is in column 3
The maximum in line 1 is in column 3
The maximum in line 2 is in column 1
>>>
```